# C# compiler can't find custom dll reference

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I have written a small ORM assembly for private purpose and wanted to check the connection string.

I had created a console application and add a reference to the assembly as I always did.

Project explorer has no warning with the file, object explorer sees all my types and namespaces in the assembly. But compiler can't resolve this reference for some reasons and I don't understand why.

I restarted Visual Studio (Express 2013) but it did not help.

Can somebody get an idea why it can't resolve that assembly reference?

[image]

Comment: What does the error say (please translate)?

Comment: Is your solution using the same version of the .net framework and targeting the same architecture (x86 or x64)?

Comment: That looks like Object Browser, showing assemblies installed in the GAC.  Maybe.  Putting your assembly in the GAC on your dev machine is a pretty bad idea.  And not enough to keep the compiler happy, you have to use Project > Add Reference.

Comment: Eror is standart "using dll error": The type or namespace name 'DBManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (sry for localization).

I'm not shure about architecture but i did not remember that had shanged it so shoud be the same ("Any CPU" by default).Versions: 4.5 (project), 4.0 (dll).

I had no registered it in GAC deliberately. May be it had been registered by compiler but i didnt heared that it is possible :)

Comment: It was a .NET version problem. Thanks for attension and sorry for mistakes :)

Comment: If you found the solution, post as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in different versions of .Net: .dll had been complied for .NET 4.6.1 and Project for .NET 4.5.

I have checked the properties of a dll and there was 4.0 runtime version setted so i was sure that version is fine.
Only compilation warning helps me to realize the reason of this problem.

Unfortunatly i get used to skip them and didn't read it right after a compilation.